# wait for animation until complete in Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am facing an issue with waiting on animation until complete. So far it was enough to use selenium functions like

> wait.until(ExpectedConditions....

but now it is not possible. I have the element in HTML

```
<div content-c2="" class="nav-loader"></div>
```

That element has the following CSS style:

```
.nav-header[content-c2] .nav-loader[content-c2] {
width: 100%;
height: 2px;
background: #EE3D42;
float: left;
clear: both;
animation: 1.5s ease-out 0.5s 1 slideInFromLeft;
```

I need to wait until the loader is complete and then I can continue with further selenium actions like click,.... I want to avoid using static delays, etc. Can anybody help me how to tailor specific function for checking once the animation completed?
Thanks for hints...

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Tried this source, but it still returns false even though the animation is done...
http://seanglover.com/blog/2012/04/wait-using-selenium-web-driver-with-jquery-animations/

Answer (score 0):

You can check the position

```
waitAnimationComplete = async(selector, newDriver = driver) => {
    const elem = await newDriver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css(selector)))
    const loc1 = await elem.getRect()

    await newDriver.wait(new Condition('wait animation complete', () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            elem.getRect()
                .then(loc2 => resolve(loc1.x === loc2.x && loc1.y === loc2.y))
        })
    }))
};
```

call

```
await waitAnimationComplete('your css selector of button ...')
```

Answer (score -1):

The animation itself works for a static time. The 1.5s and 0.5s are time in seconds.

Please check this CSS part - `animation: 1.5s ease-out 0.5s 1 slideInFromLeft;`

You will need to wait for whatever time has been provided in this CSS code.

Comment: Well, does it mean that it is static delay that is not possible to check?

Comment: It is possible to check. You can fetch this css property and put dynamic wait according to that.

Comment: But the css property is in the external css file. The DOM structure and all elements remains the same during the animation and after finishing. So no clue how to fetch it...

Comment: Whenever a page loads, all the related html and css loads as well, in whatever file it exists on the server. And we can get these properties using selenium or JavaScript, check online.